# Unwanted shutdown of selenium with goroutine

Tags: selenium, go

I'm developing using selenium in Golang.
I coded as below and run two clients using goroutine.

```golang
func RunSeleniumClient(port int) (selenium.WebDriver, *selenium.Service) {
    caps := selenium.Capabilities{"browserName": "chrome"}
    chromeCaps := chrome.Capabilities{
        Path: "",
        Args: []string{
            "--headless",
        },
    }
    caps.AddChrome(chromeCaps)

    service, err := selenium.NewChromeDriverService("./chromedriver", port)

    wd, err := selenium.NewRemote(caps, "")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    return wd, service
}

func DeleteCafeNotice() {
    driver, service := RunSeleniumClient(4444)
    defer driver.Quit()
    defer service.Stop()
    RunDelete(driver)
}

func DeleteCafeComment() {
    driver, service := RunSeleniumClient(4448)
    defer driver.Quit()
    defer service.Stop()
    RunDelete(driver)
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        DeleteCafeNotice()
        fmt.Println("End Notice")
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        DeleteCafeComment()
        fmt.Println("End Comment")
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

I developed erasing my writings and comments.
However, if one client finishes deleting first, then the other client that you are still erasing ends together.

I've tried many things to solve this problem, but it hasn't been solved, so I leave a question.

Comment: Does the code work correctly when you run DeleteCafeComment and DeleteCafeNotice one at a time in one Goroutine rather than concurrently in two?

Comment: @phonaputer Yes I've confirmed that it works.

Comment: This might not help, but you could try doing `go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) { /* ... */ }(&wg)` instead of having closures on the `sync.WaitGroup` and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @phonaputer I tried the way I told you, but it doesn't work.